# input range значения

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как выводить значения ползунка не цифрами, а буквами?

Я перемещаю ползунок и мне вместо цифры 300 пишет очень много.
пример значений:

```
1 = очень мало
10 = уже больше
50 = так гораздо лучше
100 = другое дело 
300 = хочу много
```

Есть такой код:

```
<script>
    function outputUpdate(vol) {
        document.querySelector('#volume').value = vol;
    }
</script>

<div class="toddler_item">
    <p>
        <label for=range_boy>Красивые девушки: </label>
        <output for=range_boy id="volume" >не выбрано</output>чел.
    </p>
    <div class="left_line">
        <input id="range_boy" type="range" min="1" max="500" step="1" value="1" onchange="outputUpdate(value)"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Много чего? http://jsfiddle.net/qcyet2vh/1/

Comment: ну например вы передвинули ползунок на 1 и там где написан текст не выбрано он пишет что очень мало передвинули на 10 значение поменялось на уже больше

Comment: Используйте массив с нужными значениями и проверяйте условия

Comment: можите привести пример ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function outputUpdate(vol) {
    if(vol < 30){
      document.querySelector('#volume').value = 'вы выбрали очень мало';
    }
    else {}

}
```